# File upload in php Ajax jQuery not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have simple two pages as `index.php` and `ajx_upload.php`.
And a directory for uploading files as `upload`

Below are the code

### Index.php

```
<table>
    <form name="profileimage" id="profileimage" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <tr>
            <td><img id="partner_pic" src="" height="100" width="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="fileimg1" id="fileimg1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p id="pic_profile_p"></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="uploadimg" value="Change Picture" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>

</table>
```

### ajx_upload.php

```
<?php 
     $target = "upload/"; 
     $target = $target . $_FILES['fileimg1']['name'] ; 
     $ok=1; 
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileimg1']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
     {
         echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
     } 
     else {
         echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file. <br />" . $_FILES['fileimg1']['error'];

     }
?>
```

No image or not only single is  uploaded, instead it gives an error

`Notice: Undefined index: fileimg1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\mywesbite\mydriectory\ajx_upload.php on line 3`

`Notice: Undefined index: fileimg1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\mywesbite\mydriectory\ajx_upload.php on line 5`

### jQuery Code

```
 $("#profileimage").submit(function(){

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post('ajx_upload.php', data, function(return_data){
            $('#pic_profile_p').html(return_data)
        });


        return false;
    });
```

I dont know why file is not uploaded.

Comment: because you cant send files through ajax like that , you need to look at the FileReader class in javascript DOM to send raw datas, use an iframe or use flash. With the FileReader you'll basically send an encoded string to the server as a POST data and decode it server-side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload files but use ajax, like camus said, you can't... But you can create the illusion of an ajax file upload... a little trick I use is submitting the form to a hidden iframe and then using ajax once the upload is finished to continue in your workflow as if the file was uploaded via ajax. The upload happens and the page never gets refreshed.

Check out this article http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

Comment: You can have more than 1 iframe. If an iframe is already being used for google analytics, you can create a new iframe for file uploading. Also, you may not even need to do that. If the google analytics iframe is hidden, you can even use it to upload files without affecting the functionality that you are already using it for. But, if it does affect google analytics functionality, then create a new iframe for file uploading.